# How to report apt repository working bad?

Tags: apt, repository

I found since last year uy.archive.ubuntu.com working really bad (20k downloading), so each time I install Ubuntu I have to change to archive.ubuntu.com.

I think it could be complicated for normal users in Uruguay.

I want to report this problems but I'm not sure if I should open a bug or what should I really do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO, you can file a bug about that on Launchpad. There is an example about that:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/849814

Comment: I'm working now with apt-fast to install packages, it fix any problem with slowness to some repo. :)